# Why does C# require parentheses when using nullables in an expression?

Tags: c#, nullable

I'm new to C# and while exploring the language features, I came across something strange:

```
struct Foo
{
    public Foo Identity() { return this; }

    public static void Bar(Foo? foo)
    {
        Foo foo1 = foo?.Identity().Value; // Does not compile
        Foo foo2 = (foo?.Identity()).Value; // Compiles
    }
}
```

Could anyone explain to me why the parenthesis are needed?

Comment: In the first case you are trying to access a member named `Value` in `Foo`, which does not exist. In the second statement, `Value` refers to a property of `Nullable<T>`.

Comment: If you really think about it, calling `.Value` on an expression that includes the null conditional operator is contradictory (you either expect a null or you don't).  You would most likely want to use a null coalescing operator instead, in which case the parenthesis are not needed. e.g.: `Foo foo2 = foo?.Identity() ?? <some default>`;

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Could anyone explain to me why the parenthesis are needed?

Because `Identity()` returns a `Foo` (not a `Foo?`) and thus has no `Value` property.  If `foo` is null, the null will propagate through the `Identity` call.

When you put parentheses around it, the results of the *expression* is a `Nullable<Foo>` which *does* have a `Value` property.

Also note that if `foo` *is* null, then you will be calling `Value` on a `Nullable<Foo>` that has no value, and will get an exception *at run-time*.  Some static analyzers will recognize that you have a possible null-reference exception waiting to happen and warn you.

If you expand them to their equivalents without null-propagation it will be more clear:

```
Foo foo1;
if(foo != null)
{
    foo1 = foo.Identity().Value;  // not possible - Foo has no Value property.
}
else
{
    foo1 = null;  // also not possible 
}

Foo foo2;
Foo? temp;
if(foo != null)
{
    temp = foo.Identity();
}
else
{
   temp = null;  // actually a Nullable<Foo> with no value
}
foo2 = temp.Value;  // legal, but will throw an exception at run-time if foo is null
```

> If `Identity()` returns `Foo`, why does `Foo foo3 = foo?.Identity();` not compile ?

The equivalent of that would be:

```
Foo foo3
if(foo != null)
{
    foo3 = foo.Identity();
}
else
{
    foo3 = null;  // not possible 
}
```

Comment: The joys of using the same symbol to mean different operators.

Comment: You won against my very slow computer and network :)

Comment: If `Identity()` returns `Foo`, why does `Foo foo3 = foo?.Identity();` not compile ?

Comment: Because that's how null-propagation works.  See my edit to see the equivalent without null-propagation.

Comment: I don't get it.  In your last example "The equivalent of that would be:" why is `foo3 = null;` not possible?  Also, [here, see "Return a nullable type (System.Nullable<T>) if the target member returns a value type"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx), in the case `foo.Identity().Value` the target member is `Identity()`, which returns a value type, so why isn't that promoted to a nullable type?

Comment: @davidbak 1) Because `Foo` is a _struct_ and cannot be null. 2) Because the null propagation evaluates _the entire expression_ as if the value were not null.  The reason for the parentheses is to limit the propagation to just that part of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

I think it was a good decision from the c# team to do it this way. Consider the below scenario:

If the struct was :

```
struct Foo
{
    public int ID { set; get; }

    public Foo Identity() { return this; }

    public static void Bar(Foo? foo)
    {
        int? foo1 = foo?.Identity().ID; // compile
        Foo foo2 = (foo?.Identity()).Value; // Compiles
    }
}
```

If you didn't need the parenthesis to access the Nullable result, you wouldn't be able to access the `ID` property. Since the below will not compile:

```
int? foo2 = (foo?.Identity()).GetValueOrDefault()?.ID
```

When you write `foo?.Identity().` what is after the `.` is of type `Foo` returned by `Identity()`. However in `(foo?.Identity()).` what is after the `.` is `Foo?` which is the actual result of the whole statement `foo?.Identity().`